# GridView in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview, ado.net

i am using DataGrid control. i bind it with the ADO.NET.

i want if any new data comes it should append it with the old data column wise in grid view.  how this can be done?

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = "server = (local); initial Catalog = SQLTraining; Integrated Security = SSPI";
con.Open();
string Selectstring = "select "+attribute_name+" from "+tablename+"";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Selectstring, con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);

gd.DataSource = dt;
gd.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`DataTable.Merge()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge.aspx):

```
DataTable newData = GetDataFromDatabase(); // your code there
DataTable oldData = (DataTable)gd.DataSource;
gd.DataSource = oldData.Merge(newData);
gd.DataBind();
```

---

Anyway, consider to use `using(){}` block:

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
string connectionString = "server = (local); initial Catalog = SQLTraining; Integrated Security = SSPI";
string selectCommandText = String.Format("SELECT {0} FROM {1}",
    attribute_name,
    tablename);
using (SqlConnection selectConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommandText, selectConnection))
    {
        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
    }
}
gridView.DataSource = dataTable;
gridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: @naveen: to make it even more correct, it's better to use parameterized queries. can you add that please?:)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DataTable.Merge` method. Have a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkk7s5zk.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

use this code for merge the dataset

```
dataSet.Merge(changeDataSet);
```